# Command Line FOR /F Fails

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a DOS build script which works on one Windows Server 2008 R2 but not another. To see the symptoms on the broken machine entering either of the following at the command line:

```
for /f %X in ('dir /b *.txt') do @echo %X
for /f "usebackq" %X in (`dir /b *.txt`) do @echo %X
```

gives: "'dir /b *.txt' is not recognised as an internal or external command." while e.g.

```
for %X in (*.txt) do @echo %X
```

works fine, so the /f is not being obeyed properly. I don't believe this is the Command Extensions themselves (starting cmd /x shows the same behaviour; running them inside cmd /y on the problem server gives the normal "/f was unexpected at this time"). I have also checked the command extensions registry keys and tried "setlocal enableextensions" in the batch files.

I don't think it's relevant but differences between the servers are that the failing one is physical; its CPU doesn't have VT extensions; does have McAfee installed. As far as I know they were installed the same way though at different times.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am stuck!

Comment: Looks like command line extensions are not activated. Try `setlocal enableextensions` before executing the for-loop.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried that (and errorlevel is 0 afterwards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `COMSPEC` environment variable in on the machine where it doesn't work, i.e. do `echo %COMSPEC%` and see what it contains (it should be `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` or comparable).

**Long Story:**

You're detailed question ruled out all other potential possibilities (like the need to use `%%X` instead of `%X` inside batch files, as compared to the command line), like fiddling with `setlocal enableextensions` (or comparable switches, registry entries, etc.). And by the way, the error message would not fit.

If you get the error message "...is not recognised as an internal or external command" it is, that CMD.EXE cannot find the command you're trying to execute. Since "dir" is an internal command "this should never happen", of course.

I was able to reproduce your error doing the following:

1. Start `CMD.EXE`
2. Enter the following `SET ComSpec=DoesNotExist`
3. Enter the following `CMD.EXE`, i.e. start another, nested, `CMD.EXE` session. This step is required, in a running `CMD.EXE` session, the change to `ComSpec` seems to go unnoticed.
4. In the new `CMD.EXE` session enter your command (e.g. `for /F %x in ('dir /b') do @echo%x`), you should get the error you see. Note if you just enter `dir` it will still work, so you have to have that "indirect" execution via, e.g., a `for` loop. Funny.

Note that this was all done to reproduce what you are seeing, the reasons exact environmental or setup conditions that lead to this behavior on your system might be different, however the fact that the `ComSpec` environment variable refers to something other than `CMD.EXE` should be the same.

Comment: Interesting, yes that repro's the symptoms on the good machine, however %comspec% is C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe in both cases. If context is relevant the bad machine is set as a DC unlike the good one; the problem does happens for the (domain) administrator; all access is on the console not rdp. For debugging does it make sense to copy cmd.exe somewhere, set permissions directly and point comspec at that? I'll give that a go.

Comment: @StuartBrown Where did you check the value of `%ComSpec%`? Directly in the shell where the problem happens?

Comment: Yes, I just Start -> type cmd -> `echo %comspec%` and unfortunately it all looks fine e.g. `%comspec%` starts a nested session where dir works - Version 6.1.7601 on both machines, and copying cmd.exe somewhere and pointing comspec at that gives the same situation.

Comment: This WAS the problem .. %comspec% had double quotes round it on the broken machine; I have no idea why. For the record this was diagnosed in Process Monitor - there were results `NAME INVALID` for e.g. path `C:\Users\Administrator\"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"`. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In a batch file you have to use double-percents i.e. %%X.
At the command line single percents are fine.

As to why it works on one machine, not sure, perhaps its somehow being run via 16 bit DOS on the machine which works? Or it was a different test that appears to work without the variable substituion working.

Comment: That's correct, however the OP explicitly said that he tested it on the command line.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. does just running "dir /b *.txt" work (it should).

Comment: What you get running: `for /f %X in ('set') do @echo %X` / `for /f %X in ('ver') do @echo %X`?

Comment: They give `'set' is not recognized ...` and `'ver' is not recognized ...` respectively. It really does seem that the environment is not being inherited in the `for` along the lines @Christian.K indicates. (`%comspec% /c dir` works fine, also with set or ver.)