# Can't execute exe in for-loop in clause

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, windows-7-x64

I have this in a batch file called find_java.bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('C:\Programming\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe') do (set java_exe=%%a)
```

The problem is that when I run this batch file I get:

```
'C:\Programming\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

However when the batch file contains just:

```
@echo off
C:\Programming\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe
```

it executes the command just fine.

I'm new to writing batch files, but looking at online examples this should work...

**Edit: 
Sorry for revisiting this so late.**

I found the solution. It had something to do with ComSpec for reasons I still don't quite understand. My ComSpec was

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;
```

I went into the registry and changed

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\ComSpec
```

from

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;
```

to

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

then logged out and back in and magically it worked. %SystemRoot% was C:\Windows, all the other system variables use it, and

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"C:\Programming\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe"') do (set java_exe=%%a)
```

worked perfectly, so I honestly don't understand but see [Command Line FOR /F Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668011/command-line-for-f-fails) to possibly make more sense of it than I did.

Comment: just a guess: maybe double slash ? _'C:\\Programming\\Android\\android-sdk\\tools\\lib\\find_java.exe'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally these problems are solved by enclosing the command in double quotes.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"C:\Programming\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe"') do (set java_exe=%%a)
```

But I don't see anything in your command that would require quotes.

I haven't a clue why it is not working, but the FOR /F statement is attempting to execute the command in a new CMD shell.

Try to run the following batch and see if it runs the command OK. This is the command that the FOR statement is actually attempting to run:

```
@echo off
%comspec% /c C:\Programming\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe
```

If that runs OK, then I am completely stumped. If it fails, then figuring out why should also help diagnose why the FOR /F command is failing.

Comment: I'm sorry for revisiting this almost a month later. Your post sent me on a journey that ended well though.

I tried your command and it worked fine, so I gave up, but 70 google searches later upon reading another SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668011/command-line-for-f-fails), I found he had the same problem as me, except I couldn't find any secret quotes. So not understanding his solution, I changed ComSpec in the registry to exactly what it already displayed, logged out and back in, and somehow it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps, but I just tried your sample code. It runs perfectly on a WinXP SP3 machine. Have you tried running the batch file with administrator privileges?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using "run as administrator" on cmd.exe, and I've also tried setting all the permissions on the .bat file for everyone...

Comment: Another thing you could try is adding the directory "C:\Programming\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\" to the PATH environment variable, then change the call so it looks like: 'find_java.exe'