# Issue while calling runScript.bat of OpenScript (OracleATS) from jenkins

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd, openscript

I am trying to call `runScript.bat` of `Openscript (OracleATS)` from Jenkins. There is one command to generate GUID in `runScript.bat`

`for /f %%i in ('%~d0%~p0guidgen.exe') do set GUID=%%i`

This command is always failing with error,

`'C:\OracleATS\openScript\guidgen.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

It runs fine when I call `runScript.bat` from command prompt.

What could be the possible reason for failure at this point?

Comment: Is the path to the exe correct? Is the exe actually there? %~dp0 refers to the location of the bat file, when running from jenkins are you in correct working directory for the command to work?

Comment: Answer to all your 3 questions is Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the registry setting on the machine where I was running the bat file.

More details : [Command Line FOR /F Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668011/command-line-for-f-fails)